# Which event is used in backend when deleting an article

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, shopware, shopware5

I want to know which event is used in Shopware 5 backend when we delete an article, I see in browser's network tab that **controller** *ArticleList* **method** *deleteProduct* is called

[image]

As it says, an ***"Event listener function of the product store of the backend module"***

So my question is, I am making a custom plugin where i have to add some more logic when an article is deleted.

Any event or hook which I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem this way, hope it helps someone in the future.

```
// subscribe to an event
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [
        'Enlight_Controller_Action_PostDispatchSecure_Backend_ArticleList' => 'onArticleListPostDispatch'
    ];
}

// add the logic to your subscribed method
public function onArticleListPostDispatch(\Enlight_Event_EventArgs $args)
{
    $controller = $args->getSubject();        
    $request = $controller->Request();

    if ($request->getActionName() == 'deleteProduct') {
          
            // add your logic here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use doctirne events for this: https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/models/#remove-event

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the input. I managed to solve my case with this event Enlight_Controller_Action_PostDispatchSecure_Backend_ArticleList

Comment: It's not the best way to do this, but does works too...